# Swift 3 array indexOf function is missing

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, any

When I try to print index of the array which contains any object. It's not suggesting the `indexOf` function. When I try to enter manually its shows error that I have attached screenshot.

But it's working for Array of String. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

[image]

Also Here I am showing my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var arrayOfAnyObject: [Any] = [Any]()
    var arrayOfStringObject: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


         print("Index of string object array \(arrayOfStringObject.index(of: "anyString")!)")

         print("Index of any object array \(arrayOfAnyObject.index(of: "anyObject")!)")




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to mention the array type `var arrayOfAnyObject: [Int] = [Int]()`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Its not working with "Any" datatype

Comment: you need to decalre as AnyObject for type cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either set the type that you need in the array (`Int`, `String` etc..) or convert the `arrayOfAnyObject` to `AnyObject` before you do the `indexOf`, like this:

```
print("Index of any object array \((arrayOfAnyObject as AnyObject).index(of: "anyObject"))")
```

Comment: Thanks Rashwan. Its working. Can you please tell me why Its not showing indexOF function without convert. Anyway Its a array Right ?

Comment: @Manimurugan, great. It doe not work because `Any` does not confirm to the equatable protocol. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable).

Comment: @Manimurugan.mine is not working here. why :( i just changed my data type to AnyObject what Rashwan advised. like this
var arrayOfAnyObject: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

Comment: @elk_cloner, keep your array as `Any` and when you do the `indexOf` use the example I provided.